# how to grep and checking the code using svn?

Tags: linux, svn

I'm looking for something similar to this

`find -name "*_newVersion*" | svn ci -m "newVersion checking"`

But this command line actually doesn't work, anyone knows the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to construct a command line like:

```
svn ci -m "newVersion checking" [files ...]
```

You need to pipe the output of `find` into `xargs`.

Comment: may I know the working code? Am I using the pipe correctly?

Comment: I don't use linux so I can't test your `find` or `xargs` variant, but my best guess would be: `find -name "\*_newVersion\*" |  xargs svn ci -m "newVersion checking"`